# Spatial query: A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, spatial-query

I am trying to create a parameterized stored procedure from a spatial query (SQL Server 2016). The underlying spatial query works fine when the parameter (`@long`/ longitude) is hard coded (e.g 174.7115) .

When I attempt to create a Stored Proc with a parameter for longitude (`@long`)  I get the following error.

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Spatial8, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   **A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":** 
>   System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 11 of the input. The input has @Long.
>   System.FormatException: 
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeDouble()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
>   .........................

Here is the Stored Proc..

```
CREATE PROC Spatial8 @Long decimal(9,6)
AS
DECLARE @Car geography;
SET @Car = geography::STGeomFromText ('Point(@Long -36.81143)', 4326);

/* Add 20m buffer to each side of the cars position (Lat and long) */
DECLARE @Pointbuffer geography;
SET @Pointbuffer = @Car.STBuffer ('20');

Select *, @Pointbuffer.STContains(geography ::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326 )) As PointBuffer
From dbo.Location
WHERE @Pointbuffer.STContains(geography ::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326 )) = 1
```

Any advice, suggestions, or work arounds would be appreciated.  I have tried swapping Geography to Geometry, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server will not substitute the parameter by itself in the geometry tagged text.

Create a `@geometry_tagged_text` variable of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, format it as below and pass that parameter to `geography::STGeomFromText`.

```
DECLARE @geometry_tagged_text NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @geometry_tagged_text=N'Point('+CAST(@Long AS NVARCHAR)+N' -36.81143)';

DECLARE @Car geography;
SET @Car = geography::STGeomFromText (@geometry_tagged_text, 4326);
```